# Skew symmetric and row(A) = col(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a question on some h/w that asked if $row(A)=col(A)$ then $A = A^t$.

I answered false and found somewhere that if $A^t = - A$ then $row(A) = col(A)$

does this go the other way as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is not true. Let $A$ be any invertible, non-(skew)symmetric matrix, like $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Clearly, the rows and columns span $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $A^T \neq A$ and $A^T \neq -A$.